# FORFILES in batch to delete specific suffix files older than a week

Tags: batch, script

I want to use FORFILES in batch to delete ONLY txt(beginning with `localhost_access_log`) files (not subdirectories) older than a week.
But I am getting `%%t was unexpected at this time.`

```
for %%t in (.txt) do forfiles /p "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\logs\" /s /m *%%t /d -10 /c "cmd /c del @PATH"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f useback^tokens^=* %i in (`2^>nul forfiles /p "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\logs\" /s /m "*.txt" /d -10 /c "cmd /c echo=@Path"`)do @echo\%~ni|findstr/bil localhost_access_log >nul && echo\ del/q /f "%~fi"
```

---

**1.** Not a valid mask in : `/m *%%t`

The **`%%t`** is a complete path, it is a resultant and 100% qualified element from the previous loop, but not a mask for use by `forfiles`, even if
added to **`*`**, it will not be treated as a mask.

**2.** You can replace **`/m *%%t`** to:

```
/m "*.txt"
```

**3.** Replace `For` to `For /F` loop:

```
for /f useback^tokens^=* %i in (`2^>nul forfiles /p "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\logs\" /s /m "*.txt" /d -10 /c "cmd /c echo=@Path"`)do ...
```

**4.** Use an **`echo\FileName`** to check if it matches the name of the file you want to delete, using a redirect `|` with **`Findstr`**, and the operator **`&&`** (`return 0`) to execute **`del`** if the name matches:

```
@echo\%~ni|findstr/bil localhost_access_log >nul && echo\ del /q /f "%~i"
```

**5.** Test and confirm that if you are satisfied, if so, remove the `echo` for effective deletion of the file.

```
@echo\%~ni|findstr/bil localhost_access_log >nul && del /q /f "%~i"
```

**Obs.:** - Using a `For` loop you can expand your variable:

```
    %~i   - expands %i removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %~fi  - expands %i to a fully qualified path file/dir name only
    %~ni  - expands %i to a file/dir name only
    %~xi  - expands %i to a file/dir extension only
    
    %%~nxi => expands %%~i to a file/dir name and extension
```

- ```
  Use the FOR variable syntax replacement:
      %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
      %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
      %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
  ```
- ```
  The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:
      %~pnI       - expands %I to a path and file name only
      %~pnxI      - expands %I to a path, file name and extension only
  ```

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Del /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)
- [`Echo /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [`Forfiles /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)